# Click event is just refreshing the page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

When I click the 'Submit' button the page just seems to refresh and no messages are displayed that are suppose to read either 'Completed' or 'Not'. I added was some Ajax functions to populate some drop down list dynamically for information from MySQL database.

Question: *Why is my page not submitting, it is just 'refreshing'?* (after adding the Ajax function and populating drop down list from php file)

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
function populatematerial(str)
{   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else
    {
    // IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getmaterial.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```
<form name='form1' method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td width="144">DB Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dbusername" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="144">DB Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="dbpassword" size="32"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="144">Tank Type</td>
        <td><select name="tanktype" id="tools" onChange="populatematerial(this.value)">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
        <option value="Rinse">Rinse</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="material_show" style="display:none;">
        <td width='144'>Material</td>
        <td>
        <select size='1' name='material' id="txtHint">
        </select>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="result" ></p>
```

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['result']))
{
session_start();

// check user id and password 

 if (!authorized($dbuser1,'#####')) {
  echo "<h2>You are not authorized.  Sorry.</h2>";
  // exit to different page
 }

// open database connection

// upload some data via $submitquery

mysql_query($submitquery) or die('UNABLE TO SUBMIT DATA');
echo "<b>Submit Successful</b><p>";

// close database connection

?>
```

PHP file that populates material dropdown:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

// open database connection

$query = "select * from r2rtool.platingmaterialtype where type = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$option = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $option.="<option value=\"{$row['Material']}\">{$row['Material']}</option>";
}
echo "<option value='0'></option>";
echo $option;

// close database connection
?>
```

Comment: On a side note, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] could potentially leave an opening for XSS attacks. Check out this article: http://www.mc2design.com/blog/php_self-safe-alternatives

Comment: @jwatts1980 This is on a secure internal network no public access.

Comment: Is it truly *just* refreshing the page?  A quick way to check would be to actually refresh the page after submitting to see if your browser warns you about re-posting data.  Or fire up fiddler or IE's network profiler and watch the network traffic when you click submit.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking a submit button in a form will submit the page.  If you don't want that to happen, you have to prevent it explicitly by handling the `form.onsubmit` event and cancelling the event:

```
document.forms.form1.onsubmit = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // Do something else instead here
}
```

You can also cancel the click event of the submit button:

```
document.forms.form1.result.onclick = function(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;

    // Do something else instead here
}
```

Comment: You can also just return false from the onsubmit function itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do want to submit the page. My problem is that it is not submitting the page it is just 'refreshing' the page. I know there is a problem somewhere in the Ajax because it worked before I changed to dynamically populate.

Comment: @TheRealDK - Sorry, your post title along with leading with the AJAX code was a red herring for me.  I think I understand your question now, but I'm afraid I'm no php guru and can't help much.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to gilly3's answer, you may also do return false in onclick event of the button.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" onclick="return false;" value="Click me" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the page to submit. I don't know why it is not submitting right now. It just clears fields and refreshes page, I check if the data was uploaded and nothing is in the database and nothing is printed 'Did not submit data' or 'Submit was successfully'

Comment: Well, I guess when you are using the ajax, you should call the ajax service from JS and should not refresh the page. To my understanding your button should call the ajax function and should not postback or refresh. My suggestion is stop your button from submitting the form, instead, have it call your Ajax.